# Div not positioning right according to my need

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button, on clicking it, a div appears that is hidden right below it. My issue is that the div is not scaling on large and small screens. The hidden div should be right below the image but it scatters along right and left.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div id="cel-screen"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showhide()" id="colorbt"><img src="images/colors.png" height="50" width="100" /></a>
      <div id="color-lib-1">
        <div class="row" style="margin: 5px 0 5px 0;">BASIC</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center !important;">
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(150, 0, 0);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(0, 0, 152);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(0, 151, 0);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(255, 0, 5);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 0);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(0, 255, 255);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(255, 0, 255);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(255, 150, 0);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(255, 0, 150);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(0, 255, 150);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(150, 0, 255);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        <div class="pick col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(0, 150, 255);" onclick="hello(this.style.backgroundColor,1);"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="call5()"><img src="images/previous.png" width="20" height="20" /></a>&nbsp;More Colors&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="call2()"><img src="images/next.png" width="20" height="20" /></a></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
#cel-screen {height:50px; position:relative; float:right;}
#colorbt {position:relative; bottom:0; right:0; margin:10px;}
#color-lib-1 {background-color:white;width:165px; height:300px; top:55px; display:none;border:1px solid black;position:absolute;}
```

And this is my Javascript

```
function showhide() {
    if (pressed == 0){
        document.getElementById('color-lib-1').style.display = "block";
        pressed = 1;
    } else if (pressed==1){
        if (document.getElementById('color-lib-1').style.display == "none"){
            document.getElementById('color-lib-1').style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('color-lib-1').style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Also the **MORE COLORS** should appear at the bottom of div. Any help would be much appreciated. Please see the attached image.

[image]

You can check the LIVE SITE at [here](http://colorpeutic.com/product.php?id=8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#color-lib-1 {
background-color: white;
width: 165px;
height: auto;
top: 55px;
display: none;
border: 1px solid black;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -85px;
}
```

I have just added left:50%; and margin-left: -85px; It will work for you.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the color-picker box to be display right under the #colorbtn link. You should use

```
#cel-screen{
    display:inline-block;
}
#colorbt{
    margin:0px;
}
```

[#cel-screen on display:block getting full width of parent element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d11nz.png)

[#cel-screen on display:inline-block getting only child element width + margin: 10px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwuAy.png)

I hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "position: absolute" from the #color-lib-x elements and add a margin-top of 5 or 10 pixels instead. This should center the color-lib-x elements under the image.

Comment: Sry it was a misunderstanding. I thought that there should be even more color boxes that are hidden for some reason.

Comment: there are actually 5 boxes that are hidden. I just mentioned 1. Because if the issue is resolved for 1, it would be resolved for all. Can you please look at the live site? You will see the issue there.

Comment: now you misunderstood me. i know that there are 5 boxes and i thought there is something else but there isn't.

Have you tried to change the css in the way i suggested it?

Comment: Yes I pasted just 1 box here. Can you help me with my issue?

Comment: Have you tried to change the css in the way i suggested it?

Comment: Yes but on small screen, the color-lib-1 floats to left of the screen but the button stays in center.

Comment: well, most of your elements only have a definition for the sm or lg viewport which means they won't have a proper position on smaller viewports. You should define the width of all elements along the bootstrap grid starting with xs.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I am new at bootstrap.

Comment: Please read this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid - bootstrap is mobile first wich means you should always have a definition for the xs viewport like a col-xs-12 for everything. For example if you're element only has a col-lg-6 it will get a 50% width on the lg viewport, but there will be no width definition for xs, sm or md.